# Update some fields on change and on load

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

We have the following script which runs on a change to a drop-down - updates the price based on the currency code chosen. This basically gets the value of the drop-down and updates the *priceamm* and *preicecurr* fields within the text on the page.

```
<script>
function run() {
    var f = document.getElementById("dropPrice");
    priceamm.innerHTML  = f.options[f.selectedIndex].value;
    var e = document.getElementById("dropPrice");
    pricecurr.innerHTML =  e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="dropPrice" onchange="run()" class="fa-select">
  <option value = "a">aaa</option>
  <option value = "b">bbb</option>
```

**Question**
Now, we would also like to load the drop-down to one of the options (selected) when loading the page (*onload*). We are able to populate the variables in the text but not the drop-down to show option *bbb*. In php this is quite easy but we are a bit lost with javascript. We tried something on these lines onload but does not work:

```
document.getElementById("dropPrice").value = "<?php echo $geo_price ;?>";
```

With jQuery this is probably easier but once again no luck:

```
window.onload = function() {
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      document.getElementById('dropPrice').find('option[value=<?php echo $geo_price ;?>]').attr('selected','selected');
    });
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery selector part is incorrect. You are mixing plain JS with jQuery. When you call document.getElementById('dropPrice') a regular DOM element is returned, but then you call find which is a jQuery method to be used on a jQuery element. So, you either need to wrap the first part to return a jQuery element like so:

```
$(document.getElementById('dropPrice'))
.find('option[value="b"]').attr('selected', true);
```

Or, select it via jQuery in the first place like:

```
$('#dropPrice [value="b"]');
```

However, your first example:

```
document.getElementById("dropPrice").value = "b";
```

*should* work. That makes me wonder if the value that is being echoed by PHP is correct and/or if there are other JS errors being thrown that would cause that code not to run.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The value we are loading from php is *&#8364;5* - I changed this to 5 and *document.getElementById("dropPrice").value = "5";* works. So the problem seems to be with the html display of the euro sign - any ideas?

Comment: I used the symbol and it works - Chrome was converting the html code into a symbol hence javascript was not matching the value